# How can I get top 5 properties from a JS object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting, slice

I have a JS object. I'm trying to only the top 5 values only

```
console.log(Object.keys(uniqVisitorDeviceType),Object.values(uniqVisitorDeviceType));
```

I got

```
(27) ["iPhone", "Windows NT 6.1", "Windows NT 10.0", "Macintosh", "iPad", "Windows NT 6.2", "Windows NT 6.3", "X11", "compatible", "Windows NT 5.1", "Linux", "Windows", "TweetmemeBot/4.0", ") { :", "Windows NT 6.0", "User-Agent,Mozilla/5.0 ", "KHTML, like Gecko", "Unknown", "Android", "Android 7.1.1", "Android 7.1.2", "Windows NT x.y", "Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 ", "Windows NT 5.0", "Windows NT 8.0", "web crawler :: robots.txt exclude elefent", "Windows NT"] 

(27) [198, 2197, 2381, 1271, 11, 46, 81, 417, 1752, 87, 225, 70, 8, 14, 6, 1, 6, 9, 1, 1, 2, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

How do I grab the 5 values order? order ?

```
-2381
-2197
-1752
-1271
-417
-225
-198
....
```

---

> console.log(JSON.stringify(uniqVisitorDeviceType));

yield this

```
{"iPhone":198,"Windows NT 6.1":2198,"Windows NT 10.0":2381,"Macintosh":1271,"iPad":11,"Windows NT 6.2":46,"Windows NT 6.3":81,"X11":417,"compatible":1752,"Windows NT 5.1":87,"Linux":225,"Windows":70,"TweetmemeBot/4.0":8,") { :":14,"Windows NT 6.0":6,"User-Agent,Mozilla/5.0 ":1,"KHTML, like Gecko":6,"Unknown":9,"Android":1,"Android 7.1.1":1,"Android 7.1.2":2,"Windows NT x.y":2,"Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 ":7,"Windows NT 5.0":1,"Windows NT 8.0":1,"web crawler :: robots.txt exclude elefent":1,"Windows NT":1}
```

Comment: Can you add the original object to your question too (e.g. `console.log(JSON.stringify(uniqVisitorDeviceType))`)

Comment: copy the numeric list and sort the copy, grab the top 5 values, find the index of the top 5 values in original list, use that index to grab the corresponding string from the other list?

Comment: @AKX I added the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(uniqVisitorDeviceType));`

Comment: This answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069840/6048928

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort()` to make ordered list of values of Object. And then use `slice(0,n)` get top `n` elements.

```js
let obj = {"iPhone":198,"Windows NT 6.1":2198,"Windows NT 10.0":2381,"Macintosh":1271,"iPad":11,"Windows NT 6.2":46,"Windows NT 6.3":81,"X11":417,"compatible":1752,"Windows NT 5.1":87,"Linux":225,"Windows":70,"TweetmemeBot/4.0":8,") { :":14,"Windows NT 6.0":6,"User-Agent,Mozilla/5.0 ":1,"KHTML, like Gecko":6,"Unknown":9,"Android":1,"Android 7.1.1":1,"Android 7.1.2":2,"Windows NT x.y":2,"Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 ":7,"Windows NT 5.0":1,"Windows NT 8.0":1,"web crawler :: robots.txt exclude elefent":1,"Windows NT":1}


let res = Object.values(obj).sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,5);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Mine is not an array it is an object. Can you please adjust your answer to fit that ?

Comment: I added it to my post.

Comment: @kyo And can you please add expected output for top five. What you want numbers or the keys?

Answer (score 2):

This will help:

```js
const obj = {"iPhone":198,"Windows NT 6.1":2198,"Windows NT 10.0":2381,"Macintosh":1271,"iPad":11,"Windows NT 6.2":46,"Windows NT 6.3":81,"X11":417,"compatible":1752,"Windows NT 5.1":87,"Linux":225,"Windows":70,"TweetmemeBot/4.0":8,") { :":14,"Windows NT 6.0":6,"User-Agent,Mozilla/5.0 ":1,"KHTML, like Gecko":6,"Unknown":9,"Android":1,"Android 7.1.1":1,"Android 7.1.2":2,"Windows NT x.y":2,"Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 ":7,"Windows NT 5.0":1,"Windows NT 8.0":1,"web crawler :: robots.txt exclude elefent":1,"Windows NT":1};

const top5Values = Object.values(obj).sort((a,b) =>b-a).slice(0,5);

const top5Keys = Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => obj[b]- obj[a]).slice(0,5);

console.log(top5Keys, top5Values)
```

Comment: interesting answer. Thanks 

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- `Object.entries()` to get string/number pairs from your data,
- sort them with a custom comparison function that looks at the numbers within the pairs
- use `.slice(0, 5)` to limit things to the top 5

The return value is an array of 2-arrays.

```
const data = {
    "iPhone": 198,
    "Windows NT 6.1": 2198,
    "Windows NT 10.0": 2381,
    "Macintosh": 1271,
    "iPad": 11,
    "X11": 417,
    "compatible": 1752,
    // ... snip ...
};

const top5 = Object.entries(data).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]).slice(0, 5);

console.log(top5);
```

outputs

```
[ [ 'Windows NT 10.0', 2381 ],
  [ 'Windows NT 6.1', 2198 ],
  [ 'compatible', 1752 ],
  [ 'Macintosh', 1271 ],
  [ 'X11', 417 ] ]
```